# How to add prefix to macro symbol?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am looking for general solution to the problem as stated in the title. But as illustration consider my real case. I would like to get `wstring`, like this:

```
L"hello"
```

but when I have a macro:

```
#define MACRO(S) ...
```

and a call:

```
MACRO("hello") // no L prefix
```

how to define it to get `wstring`, as before?

```
L S
```

is treated as 2 symbols.

Comment: btw, do you know that most compilers will show you the post processing stuff if you ask for it? eg gcc take a -E flag to just run the pre-processer, which is very handy when experimenting (though that does includes too, so there is a lot of "surplus" stuff in it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the paste operator, look up # and ## for the pre-processor for exciting new opportunities to both solve problems and create interesting new ones.

http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator.html

but for your specific question, try:

```
#define MACRO(S) L ## S
```

In my personal experience, the paste operator is one of the best genuine uses for macros in C++ since it gives you something you can't easily do without it. But like most pre-processor features, it is often used for evil.

As a history note, there were early C compilers where you could write `#define MACRO(S) L/* */S` which people did, because they legitimately wanted token pasting, but it didnt formally exist. I believe these days the comment hack will explicitly not work in standard complying pre-processors.

Comment: I have seen production code use this feature for doing template style stuff in straight C. It can be a path to hell, so dont say you weren't warned.

Comment: Thank you very much. As for danger, there is always some risk with macros, but if you know you are doing...

Answer (score 5):

## Basics.

The straightforward way is to use preprocessor **token pasting**, the `##` preprocessor operator, as follows:

```
#define MACRO( s ) L ## s
```

## General solution.

You state that you're looking for a "general solution", and the basic token pasting isn't very general.

In particular the straightforward macro gets awkward when you want to define a long string like

```
L"Blah blah\n"
L"Second line\n"
L"Third line"
```

You'd then have to write e.g.

```
MACRO( "Blah blah\n" )
MACRO( "Second line\n" )
MACRO( "Third line" )
```

Happily you can use C++11 **variadic macros** to support an arbitrary number of arguments, writing the above literal like this:

```
MACRO(
    "Blah blah\n",
    "Second line\n",
    "Third line"
    )
```

with `MACRO` defined as just, for example,

```
#   define WITH_L_PREFIX_( lit )     L##lit
#   define MACRO( ... )              MM_APPLY( WITH_L_PREFIX_, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Then the problem is reduced to defining `MM_APPLY`, e.g. like this:

```
#define MM_APPLY( macroname, ... ) \
    MM_INVOKE( \
        MM_CONCAT( MM_APPLY_, MM_NARGS( __VA_ARGS__ ) ), \
        ( macroname, __VA_ARGS__ ) \
        )
```

which in turn reduces the problem to defining `MM_INVOKE`, `MM_CONCAT`, `MM_NARGS`, and the more specific `MM_APPLY_1` through e.g. `MM_APPLY_21`, or whatever your preferred limit on number of arguments is. The reason for this is mainly to support the Visual C++ preprocessor, which isn't quite standard-conforming.

Regarding `MM_ARGS`, which produces the number of arguments, see original code by Laurent Deniau, "**VA_NARG**," 17 January 2006, in the Usenet group <comp.std.c>, e.g. as archived at (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.std.c/d-6Mj5Lko_s).

For the rest, starting with `MM_APPLY_`*n*, these definitions look like…

```
#define MM_APPLY_1( macroname, a1 ) \
    MM_INVOKE_B( macroname, (a1) )

#define MM_APPLY_2( macroname, a1, a2 ) \
    MM_INVOKE_B( macroname, (a1) ) \
    MM_APPLY_1( macroname, a2 )

#define MM_APPLY_3( macroname, a1, a2, a3 ) \
    MM_INVOKE_B( macroname, (a1) ) \
    MM_APPLY_2( macroname, a2, a3 )
```

which, again for reasons of supporting a specific compiler (namely g++ this time) introduces `MM_INVOKE_B`.

```
#define MM_INVOKE( macro, args ) macro args
#define MM_INVOKE_B( macro, args ) macro args     // For nested invocation with g++.
```

`MM_CONCAT` is simple,

```
#define MM_CONCAT__( a, b )     a ## b
#define MM_CONCAT_( a, b )      MM_CONCAT__( a, b )
#define MM_CONCAT( a, b )       MM_CONCAT_( a, b )
```

And that's that, roughly.

This constitutes a little "macro framework" to apply an operation to each argument.

Comment: +1. I'm curious about "*C++11 variadic macros*". Is this C++11? Isn't it inherited from C and had existed in C++03 also?

Comment: @Nawaz: As far as I know variadic macros were introduced in C99. They were not part of C++03. C++03 was just the first (and only) Technical Corrigendum of C++98, which was based C89.

Comment: C++11 is your friend. Especially if you liked C99.

Comment: I am sorry that I can only add +1 for your answer :-) Great reading, thank you!